# Checking if a node is of a given type in Godot 4

Tags: godot, godot-4

I want to check if the player is near a door.

In practice, this means that I want to check if the `Area2D` of the player node overlaps a door node (an `Area2D` with an attached `door.gd` script). This is working in Godot 3:

`player.gd`

```python
# ...

var door_type = preload("res://objects/door.gd")

# ...

for area in $Area2D.get_overlapping_areas():
    if area is door_type:
        # ...
```

`door.gd`

```python
extends Area2D

# ...
```

However, in Godot 4 (v4.1.2) I have the following error:

> "door_type" is a variable but does not contain a type.

I tried an Internet search for this error, but I did not find any result.

How can I achieve this behavior in Godot 4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Preload the script into a constant:

```
const door_type = preload("res://objects/door.gd")
```

Then `is` should work.